Swing mechanism powering
I’m working on a project where I want to repurpose a read/write head mechanism from an old HDD. This mechanism consists of a coil positioned above a magnet, and I aim to use it as a swinging mechanism. My target frequency for the swing is around 10 Hz.
For powering the coil, I have +5V (Vcc) and ground available. I’m considering using a 555 timer IC to drive the coil. Here’s a basic outline of the circuit I’m planning (see picture below):

555 Timer: Configured in astable mode to generate the 10 Hz frequency.
BD139 and BD140 Transistors: To handle the current required by the coil.


I’d appreciate your feedback on this design. Are there any improvements or alternative solutions that might be simpler or more effective for this application? Also, are the BD139 and BD140 transistors suitable for driving the coil in this setup?

What is the intended current that you want to go through the coil?

That is good question. That is basically a voice coil there. 100mA, 200mA would be my current quess. I probably have to test that a bit.

At a minimum, you're going to need a base resistor for each transistor.

That's a strange way to draw an H-bridge.  You're going to have significant cross-conduction when your drive signal is above 0.7 V and below 5 V - 0.7 V, so at a minimum make sure you get through that region very quickly.  Why not use FETs instead of bipolars?

10Hz seems very fast for something described as "swinging". 10Hz seems more like "vibrating" to me. Is this a very small structure you're manipulating?

@John D. Thank you, you just gave me a few new keywords to look at: H-bridge and FET. I happen to have those BD139 and BD140 transistors in hand, not any technical reason to select those transistors.

@brhans: Idea is turn a small mirror or a tiny prism about 40 degrees to make a beam of light (laser pointer) make a line. That HDD actuator should be able to move that quickly. And 10Hz isn't a fixed value. But idea is move that point in the way it looks like a line.

@JohnD: Why FET would be better transistor here than bipolars? And which model you would use for H-bridge?

FETs can switch (esp off) faster, they include a body diode which can catch the inductive energy without having to add external diodes, and though the peak gate drive current can be high, the gates are capacitive and once on you don't have to supply current to keep it on.  The threshold voltage is higher than a VBE, so if you use your proposed topology there would be less time in the shoot through region.
